# C++ Basic function program wont compile with a screen worth of errors

Tags: c++

This program is giving me a full screen of errors when i try to compile it with g++ but i didnt even start the hard part. Just printing instructions. What is wrong here?

```
/* Samuel LaManna
CSC 135 Lisa Frye
Program 2 Functions (Shipping Charges)
Calculate the shipping and total charge
for shipping spools of wire
*/

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void instruct();     //Function Declaration for instruction function

int main()
{
  instruct();     // Function to print instructions to user

  return 0;
}


/********************************************/
// Name: Instruct                            /
// Description: Print instructions to user   /
// Parameters: N/A                           /
// Reture Value: N/A                         /
/********************************************/

void instruct()
{
  cout << "This program will calculate the shipping information "
       << "for a batch of wire spools. " << endl < endl;

  return;
}
```

Comment: Provided overlap in the images. http://imageshack.us/g/829/39224773.png/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one problem:

```
<< endl < endl;
```

It should be:

```
<< endl << endl;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i looked it over and couldnt hind anything. Im really embarrassed now. It compiled without 1 error

Comment: @SamLaManna: Don't be embarrassed. G++'s error messages are atrocious.

Comment: It's not just G++, it's the majority of the C++ compilers. They tried to introduce "concepts" to make them better (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concepts_%28C%2B%2B%29), but it wasn't ready in time for C++11.